# Html2canvas wont render content from jqplot

Tags: jquery, jqplot, html2canvas

I have a web app that will generate charts and i am using jquery jqplot to the the task.

My web app also allows screenshot and i use html2canvas to to it.All the rendering works fine but html2canvas wont capture the charts generated by jqplot it capture an empty box.

Im using the latest version of html2canvas **html2canvas 0.5.0-alpha**, code below is how i initialize html2canvas.

```
 html2canvas($('#container'), {
                logging: true
            }).then(function(canvas) {
                $('body').append(canvas);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The 0.5 version isn't stable yet. It didn't support copying the canvas contents 2 days ago, but [f517a3578](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/commit/f517a35781c56aed5ec50276387978937c8de105) fixed that.

Example of working implementation, with latest version (HEAD from master): http://jsfiddle.net/shtj6zL9/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
});

document.querySelector("#create").addEventListener("click", function() {
 html2canvas(document.body, {logging: true}).then(function(canvas) {
     document.body.appendChild(canvas);
 }).catch(function(error) {
     console.log(error);
 });   
}, false);
```

Comment: It works fine but when its on multiple series the last series wont render. Please see this link http://jsfiddle.net/shtj6zL9/3/